# Values Between Views

Tags: sencha-touch-2

im new in sencha and have a problem.

I hace a list with information ( name and picture ) and need another with the detail, i follow de example who provide the documentation. My problem is that i can't use the values of the first list. Values like name, photo, etc...

The problem is here:

```
Ext.define('app.view.ArtistDetail',{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'artistdetail',
config: {
    tpl: tpl,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 50,
        tpl: '{title}'  <-- PROBLEM !!!!
    }]
}
});
```

The tpl: tpl, is like this and show the information correct but i can't get the title in the items section...

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<div class="global">',
            '<div class="artist-foto">',
                '<img src="{field_foto}" />',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="artist-title">',
                '{title}',
            '</div>',
        '</div>'
        );
```

THx for help !!!

Answer (score 2):

According to: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component
every Ext.Component has configs:

**data** and **tpl** that are related between each other.
So you also have to set data config:

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  id: 'myPanel',
  height: 50,
  tpl: '{title}',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello world'
  }
}
```

Also you can set data using controller:

```
onListItemTap: function(view, index, target, record) {

  var myPanel = Ext.getCmp('myPanel');
  if (myPanel) {
    myPanel.setData(record.data);
    Ext.getCmp('viewport').setActiveItem(myPanel);
  }

}
```

Here you set data from your list item to your details panel.

Comment: Oh, sorry billSummary is myPanel. So, myPanel.setData(record.data) sets data and myPanel.getData() - gets data :)